# Functions in Haskell - Understanding

Tags: function, haskell, map-function, function-call

I have the following code which gives out `[2,4,6]` :

```
j :: [Int]
j = ((\f x -> map x) (\y -> y + 3) (\z -> 2*z)) [1,2,3]
```

Why? It seems that just the "z-function" is being used, what happens to the "y-function"?
And how does `map` work in this particular case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's compute:

```
((\f x -> map x) (\y -> y + 3) (\z -> 2*z)) [1,2,3]
                 ^^^ f ^^^^^^^ ^^^ x ^^^^^
=
(map x) [1,2,3]
   where f = \y -> y +3
         x = \z -> 2*z
=
[x 1,x 2,x 3]
   where f = \y -> y +3
         x = \z -> 2*z
=
[2*1,2*2,2*3]
   where f = \y -> y +3
         x = \z -> 2*z
=
[2,4,6]
   where f = \y -> y +3
         x = \z -> 2*z
```

As we can see, `f` was taken as an argument, but was never used after that. Consequently `\y -> y+3` never affected the final result.

The function `map x` is the function that applies function `x` to each element of a list. Note that, above, `(map x) [1,2,3]` is the same as `map x [1,2,3]`. Indeed, each function application `g x1 x2 x3 x4` can be equivalently written as `(((g x1) x2) x3) x4` by left-associating the applications.

Comment: Thank you for that really good explanation!